# Creating a Migration in an existing c# project

Tags: c#, .net, database-migration

I've been struggling to create a Migration on an existing (and older) c#/.net project.

To clarify: I'm fairly new to C# and am especially struggling with Startup and Configuration constructs so I would appreciate you to be precise on what to do otherwise I'll just end up more confused ;) Thanks in advance.

**My Problem**

I'm trying to create the Migration using the following "dotnet ef" command in PowerShell:

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ..\MainProjectFolder  migrations add CourseAndDependencies
```

The Project has two project folders as such:

```
\MainProjectFolder
    |-- Contains:
        - Statup.cs
        - appsettings.json
        - Controllers + Services
\SecondaryProjectFolder
    |-- Contains:
        - Migrations
        - Models
        - an "UpdateDB.txt" containing the "instruction"
          on how to create a migration containing the dotnet ef command up above.
```

As instructed in the "UpdateDB.txt" I execute the command inside the SecondaryProjectFolder.

When I'm trying to execute the command I get the error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'DatabaseContext'. Add an
> implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to
> the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for
> additional patterns supported at design time.

I'm a bit afraid of meddling with the project as it seems to have worked somehow for my ex-coworkers but I tried to implement an IDesignTimeDbContextFactory which led to another error ("multiple DatabaseContext" found). In the meantime I've deleted that part of code.

I then found the following thread: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/issues/1080#issuecomment-504665885

suggesting to create a "DbContext with default constructor (that is, a parameterless constructor)" so I added `public DatabaseContext() : base()` to the DatabaseContext Class additional to the existing constructor. But that left me with a new error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
> provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
> method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
> If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
> accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
> passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

This is where I get stuck because I don't understand exactly what it wants me to do. This is what I found in the code which already does some things stated in that last error (in my opinion).

*Startup.cs*

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger, ILoggerFactory iLoggerFactory) {
    LoggerFactory = iLoggerFactory;
    _ilogger = logger;
    Configuration = configuration;
    DatabaseContext.StartupContext();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options
                    .UseNpgsql(sqlConnectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("SecondaryProjectFolder")));
}
```

*DatabaseContext.cs*

```
public DatabaseContext(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base (options) {
    Logger = loggerFactory;
    this.Filter<BaseEntity>(DbFilter.SoftDelete, q => q.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted));
    QueryFilterManager.InitilizeGlobalFilter(this);
}

public static void StartupContext() {
    AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.SoftDeleted<ISoftDelete>(x => x.IsDeleted);
    QueryFilterManager.ForceCast = true;
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
    optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(Logger);
}
```

Can anyone point me into the direction I need to go to be able to create this Migration?
Any help is highly appreciated!